# can form has two actions to php?

Tags: php, forms, fopen, fwrite

I'm just playing around with the form action and php.  I'm not good at them, just starting to learn and recently I was playing around with the fopen, fwrite and fclose.  Also playing around with basic form filling then php calls out what is filled.

What I'm wondering is, I know fopen, fwrite can be called to open/create a txt file and input simple data entered into the txt file but if I want to do that and also let the user see what they entered.

Not too good with explaining.  Let's say for example

a.html --> let's say in this html

```
<form action="a.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
```

a.php -->after clicking submit in a.html this a.php will have the code of

```
echo "My name is $_GET["name"]";
```

which will show My name is xxxxx after clicking submit in a.html
but what if I also want the submit in a.html to go into another let's say b.php and b.php will have the coding such as

```
$filehandle = fopen("text.txt","a+") or die ("sorry error");
fwrite($filehandle, $_GET["name"]);
fclose($filehandle);
```

I know if from a.html to go into just one of a.php or b.php then it will work but is it possible to make both a.php and b.php works with just one submit click on a.html?

*don't want to involve javascripts and those more advanced because I'm not up to that level yet but I'm just thinking if there's a simple and possible way*

Comment: no, even if possible, its not a good idea, but you can include second file in the first file then do what you want.

Comment: This is possible with javascript.

Comment: @NickFury: requires duplicating the form using JavaScript, one form can has one action.

Comment: Like Akam I suggest including `b.php` via `include 'b.php'` into `a.php`.

Answer (score 0):

best to use javascript for this one.  AFAIK, when you submit the form, it will load your target page passing the form variables specified in the form.

You can 1) use javascript to implement ajax to invoke your php scripts in your desired order

or 2)

on yourform target page, in the PHP invoke any additional PHP code you need to execute

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define two different functions for that.

```
function echoUsername($username) {
   echo "My name is $_GET["name"]";
}
function writeNameToFile($username) {
   $filehandle = fopen("text.txt","a+") or die ("sorry error");
   fwrite($filehandle, $_GET["name"]);
   fclose($filehandle);
}
```

Now just put these to a file called `functions.php`, include it into `a.php`/`b.php` using `include("functions.php");` and call the functions like this:

```
echoUsername($username);
writeNameToFile($username);
```

If you really want to call both pages, there is no way around javascript but it's still going to be a bad solution.

Comment: ah, alright....I get what you mean now....let me try this later :P
I know it's not the best way without using javascript but since I'm not at the javascript level yet and thought of such thing so curious if it is possible ^_^

Answer (score 0):

you need to include `b.php` in `a.php` like

```
<form action="a.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
```

In your `a.php` file you need to include

```
require_once "b.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

in **a.php**:

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];   // use post as the form method is better

    // then give it to **b.php**:

    header('location: b.php?name='.$name);

    // or

    echo "<a href='b.php?name='".$name.">Link to Page B</a>";
?>
```

You can get this value in **b.php** by:

```
<?php
      $new_name = $_GET['name'];   // get from the query string
?>
```